# fetch/promises - ASPX method to return a serialize DataTable (Newtonsoft) - return Array of Json objects

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, fetch

I have a web service on C# .ASMX.

Inside this class, I have the following method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void getJson()
{
    DataTable data = "SELECT * FROM AT_MasterData Order by [Order]".fwSqlFillDataTable();

    string strResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString());
    Context.Response.Flush();

    Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
}
```

The method works perfectly... but when I'm trying to get this response using a fetch / promise on Javascript I got the following error:

**Error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input**

JS Code:

```
function getJson(sectionActual) {
    let url = './services/assessment.asmx/getJson';
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json'); // This one is enough for GET requests

    fetch(url,
        {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: headers
        })
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(resultData => {
            console.log(resultData)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("Error", err));

}
```

If I change the .json() to .text() on the promise I got the result...

JS Working code:

```
function getJson(sectionActual) {
    let url = './services/assessment.asmx/getJson';
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json'); // This one is enough for GET requests

    fetch(url,
        {
            method: "POST", 
            headers: headers
        })
        .then(result => result.text())
        .then(resultData => {
            console.log(resultData)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("Error", err));
}
```

A screen of the console:
[image]

Exists a workaround to use the promise .json() to convert the data automatically?

I suppose the problem is the method does not return a JSON structure... return an array with JSON data (split each item data row in a JSON object in the array)

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, paste the actual text so we can determine whether it's valid or not

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: You are right, the method misses the last bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple...
Only include a + 1 into the header line:

```
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", (strResponse.Length + 1).ToString());
```

But, I not can define the reason to add +1 into the content-length.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void getJson()
{
    DataTable data = "SELECT * FROM AT_MasterData Order by [Order]".fwSqlFillDataTable();

    string strResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", (strResponse.Length + 1).ToString());
    Context.Response.Flush();

    Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
}
```

If I try to return a generic class converted to JSON, I need remove this +1 (The following code not return the content to JS):

```
strResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { test = "Hello World" });

Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", (strResponse.Length + 1).ToString());
Context.Response.Flush();

Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
```

This promise not resolve with `.json()` or `.text()` - both don't work...

But, if I remove the +1 from the content-length... works:

```
strResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { test = "Hello World" });

Context.Response.Clear();
Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", (strResponse.Length).ToString());
Context.Response.Flush();

Context.Response.Write(strResponse);
```

Result:

[image]